# Injection with uncountable domain

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need some help proving the following statement:

If $f: A \to B$ is injective and $A$ is uncountable, then $B$ is uncountable.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I think you misunderstood a key aspect of this site. This is more about *helping* you find the right answer then giving you answers to arbitrary problems. For example, if you were to give us what you've tried, where you've looked, what you've read to answer the problem, and describe why you aren't satisfied/doubt what you've come across, I'm sure others would help. Also, choosing a descriptive title that described the content would help. For more, I recommend reading [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9754)

Comment: Thank you for that. I know that an injective function is a one-to-one function. Would it make sense to use proof by contradiction? If I do this, then I assume that B is countable. Then there is the step I do not understand, where to go from there. Please let me know if I am in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the image of $A$, that is, the set $f(A)=\{b\in B| \exists a\in A \textrm{ such that }f(a)=b\}$. You can then show fairly easily that this set is bijective to $A$ in the obvious way (that is, the bijection between the two is obvious). If they are bijective, then what can you say about the cardinality of $f(A)$? Since $f(A)\subseteq B$, what can you say about the cardinality of $B$?

Comment: So should I focus on the fact that they are bijective even if it only states that it is injective? If that's the case then if B is a subset of A, the cardinalities should be the same, right? Meaning that if f(A) is uncountable then f(B) MUST be uncountable?

Comment: @19515 First of all, I'm not saying that $B$ is bijective to $A$. I'm saying that $f(A)$ is bijective to $A$, which you can show via a bijection between the two.

Comment: I'm so sorry I misread your answer, but I think I understand. Thank you so much.